# vanilla js routing not working, only displays [object XMLDocument]

Tags: javascript, jquery, routes

I am trying to add routing to my js application, based on this example: [link](https://codepen.io/ynonp/project/editor/XVvNYO) but in the end even if i just copy the whole proejct every file, i only get  [object XMLDocument] displayed in the `<main></main>` tags.
Why is that and how could i make it work?

Comment: Most likely your code is incorrect ..? How do you think we'd fix your code, if you're not showing it ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code in the [code pen project](https://codepen.io/ynonp/project/editor/XVvNYO) mentioned above, you need to explicitly define what are you expecting from the AJAX request. In this case, you want to accept an HTML page.

in the `page.js`, change to this line

```
$.get(this.url, {}, null, 'html')
    .then(res => this.html = res);
```